# Nginx url rewrite rules

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have URL like this:

```
http://example.com/site1
http://example.com/site2
     ...  ...
http://example.com/siten
```

Yes, there are a list of sites.

But actually I would like to access the subsites by( take `site1` for example ):

```
http://site1.example.com
```

What I have done in `nginx.conf` was :

```
if ($host = site1\.example\.com){
    rewrite ^/(.*) /example.com/site1/$1 break;
```

}

Yeah, test in local machine and I have edited `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1  example.com
```

But not work. Can anyone explains?

Comment: You got me wrong: not `127.0.0.1  example.com`, but `127.0.0.1  subdomain.example.com` and make sure that space between `...0.1  subdomain...` is either tab space or few empty space characters. Best bet is to copy existing entry in hosts file that was before you have edited anything and simple to replace existing with 127.0.0.1 subdomain.example.com. Cheers

Comment: I have solved this with the help of my workmate. It should be :
add `proxy_set_header HOST $host;`  and `if ($host = site1.example.com) {
    rewrite ^/(.*) /site1/$1 break;
}` . Of course, I should add `127.0.0.1 site1.example.com` in `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 1):

You MUST specify CNAME record for subdomain feature. Without it, no web server config rule will work.

In your DNS record management panel (whatever you use), you must create subdomain.domain.com and point DNS A record to IP where is domain.com is routed.

For local machine find hosts file, open it with administrator privileges and add 127.0.0.1       subdomain.domain.com in new line.

Comment: What should I do in local machine?

Comment: Edit hosts file. Find hosts file and type for example, 127.0.0.1 sub.example.com